# dsPIC 30F2020 Primary Oscillator

Tags: pic, oscillator

What *exactly* is the Primary Oscillator in the dsPIC 30F2020? How accurate is it? How does it compare with the Internal Fast RC Oscillator (FRC) on the same device? (I know this is more than 1 question, but are strngly related, so I hope it's no problem... `:)`)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary oscillator is the oscillator you connect externally to the device via the OSC1 and OSC2 pins. The external oscillator is either an external clock signal, external RC network or an external crystal.

Depending on what you connect to the OSC1 and OSC2 pins, the FRC could be more accurate or less accurate than the external oscillator.

See the [oscillator reference](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70054e.pdf), section 7.5 for detailed information.

Comment: So basically the 'Primary Oscillator' (black) box hides in fact nothing but a kind of 'selector switch' used to choose the exact type of the (external) oscillator?

Comment: @CountZero: basically yes. It also hides the on-chip inverter gate used to power the crystal, and the power setting for that inverter -- in a [Pierce oscillator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierce_oscillator) -- which are activated when you set the fuse bits for XTL, XT, or HS mode.

Comment: Thanx! `:)` Now it all makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer and related comments are mainly true but may mislead.

The "primary oscillator" is an ON chip piece of circuitry that can either self oscillate when selected resonant feedback paths are connected between OSC1 and OSC2 OR can have an external clock signal fed in via OSC1 (usually).

On the IC block diagram this may be shown as an inverter.
 Exactly what bits and pieces the IC designers have included as well as a simple inverter to make the circuitry better suited to its intended role is unknown unless you look at the silicon or they provide extra information in the notes.The data sheet will tell you how the something-like-a-simple-inverter behaves and you can choose how you prefer to meet the listed requirements.

A / the important thing is that it is NOT just a selector switch, it is in fact the core of an oscillator in the normal and proper sense of the word but they give you the option to drive it with an external signal and the option to choose external feedback components.

While they may not list all the following, the excessively enthused may be able to make it oscillate acceptably using any of crystal, ceramic resonator, LC circuit, RC circuit, [getting less likely: SAW filter, tunnel diode , ...], [[to make the point only: resonant cavity, tuned transmission line, waveguide, ...]]